# Division of a Price in Django Template Syntax

Tags: css, django

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get a 1/4 of a price in a Django Template Editor.

`quote.total` is a generated value by the system, for example: 1235.00, and I need to manipulate that value to show 308.75 (1235.00 divided by 4).

I've tried things like using `{% widthratio quote.total 4 1 %}` to get the quotient, however widthratio rounds the quotient, and I need an exact one.

I've also tried `{% widthratio quote.total 4 100 %}`, to get the quotient multiplied by 100 (implying that all I'd need to do is figure out how to place a decimal point two places over), but have found no way of using CSS to place a decimal point in.

It is also worth noting that because of the products I am working with `quote.total` will never have a value in the tenths or hundreths place. I've tried using that to my advantage by adding modulus operators and complex math rules & logic with no success.

The one problem with the system I am using is I have no access to the backend to create custom functions, and because of the way the system parses the template, I cannot use script tags.

Comment: Is the intended purpose for the result of this division plain text in your template or some CSS as the primary tag on this question suggests?

Comment: The intended purpose for the result is to return plain text. I tagged CSS because I wonder if there is a CSS attribute that will format the number, maybe some manipulation of ::before or ::after? I did not realize it was the primary tag, I'll fix that.

Comment: The better place for such manipulations of data is the `view`. Business logic should never be in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see you cannot use tags since you have no access to the back end.  You may need a JS-based solution.  I'll leave this answer up in case it helps someone.

This is a pretty common use case. Consider using a custom filter, something like:

**template.html**

```
{% load quarter %}

{{quote.total|quarter}}
```

**/your_app/templatetags/quarter.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def quarter(value):
        
    return (float(value) * 0.25)
```

Documentation on custom filters is [here in the Django Docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)  Also, as with any template tag, be sure to restart your server after adding it, or it will django will not register the tag and will throw an error.  This is true of production and development servers.